# Difference between $\sin x$, $x$ and $\tan x$ when $x \to 0$

Tags: limits

What is the exact difference between the limits of $\sin x\over x$, $x\over \sin x$, $\tan x \over x$ and $x \over\tan x$ when $x \to 0$? They all approximate to 1,but I was wondering if it has any difference between writing $\sin x\over x$ and $\tan x\over x$ in most situations.

Comment: Note that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ approaches $1$ from below (as $x\to 0$), while $\frac{\tan x}{x}$ approaches $1$ from above, i.e. $$ \frac{\sin x}{x} \lt 1 \lt \frac{\tan x}{x} $$ for $|x|\in  (0,\pi/2)$. Whether it is an important difference depends on context.  "Most situations" is not a very precise constraint.

Comment: @hardmath Ah. Is it because sinx increases slowly compared to x when x is close to 0 and tanx increases faster? Can you give a situation that demonstrates this exact difference?  Thanks

Comment: See the nice picture of @Shaswata in Answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

For any angle $x$,

$$\text{Area of smaller triangle}<\text{Area of part of circle subtending angle x}<\text{Area of larger triangle}$$

$$\frac{1}{2} \sin x<\frac{1}{2} x<\frac{1}{2} \tan x$$

$$\rightarrow \frac{\sin x}{x}<1<\frac{\tan x}{x}$$

Comment: Also note that $x$ is the length of the circular arc between the $\sin x$ vertical and the $\tan x$  vertical.

Comment: Although we cannot compare the lengths directly just by looking at it. For example the arc length could've been greater than the $\tan x$ vertical.

Comment: Fair point, although we _can_ tell by inspection that the arc $x$ is longer than the hypotenuse of the $(\sin x, 1-\cos x)$ right triangle, and hence $x \ge \sin x$ (with equality when $x=0$).

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}\to\frac{1}{1}=1$$ as $\lim\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\lim f(x)}{\lim g(x)}$ so : $$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$$ and both have their limits as $1$ and the same with $\tan x$